# How to use CanExecute with Mvvmcross

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a Button

```
<Button 
      android:id="@+id/ButtonConnect"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Disconnect"
      local:MvxBind="{'Click':{'Path':'DisconnectCommand'}}" />
```

And I have a Command for it

```
public IMvxCommand DisconnectCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxRelayCommand(this.GetService<IConnectionService>().Disconnect);
    }
}
```

Then I want to enable/disable the DisconnectCommand using

```
DisconnectCommand.CanExecute(this.GetService<IConnectionService>().UsbConnected);
```

But thats clearly wrong (It is not working), I put the check in as a a parameter, but normally I would do

```
DisconnectCommand.CanExecute = someBool;
```

But there is no property to set, so how to go about this?

Comment: Is `UsbConnected` a method or a property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To work out how to use `CanExecute`, take a look at Silverlight or WPF - there's lots of blogs out there which talk about how to use `ICommand` - e.g. http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2009/12/02/using-icommand-silverlight-4.aspx or http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/26/using-relaycommands-in-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx

An example would be something like:

```
private MvxRelayCommand _disconnectCommand;
public IMvxCommand DisconnectCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_disconnectCommand == null)
            _disconnectCommand = new MvxRelayCommand(this.GetService<IConnectionService>().Disconnect, item => this.IsItemConnected(item));
        return _disconnectCommand;
    }
}

private void SomeServiceNotificationHandler()
{
    _disconnectCommand.RaisePropertyChanged();
}

private bool IsItemConnected(object thing)
{
    return /* your code */;
}
```

---

There is one small problem though....

`CanExecute` isn't really fully implemented across all the MvxBindings across all platforms... It will work for some of them, but for some of them it won't - and I don't really know which ones at present! If you come across issues, then please let me know (via GitHub issues) and they will get fixed...

---

Personally... I don't tend to use `CanExecute` - I tend instead to use a separate Boolean property which I then bind to whatever property is available on the control - e.g. most controls have something like `Enabled`, `IsEnabled`, `Disabled`, `IsDisabled`, etc.

I generally find it easier (and more readable) to set the Boolean property rather than to call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`

e.g. I'd use something like:

```
<Button 
  android:id="@+id/ButtonConnect"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Disconnect"
  local:MvxBind="{'Click':{'Path':'DisconnectCommand'},'Enabled':{'Path':'UsbConnected'}}" />
```

You can definitely argue that the `CanExecute` approach has advantages - because it keeps the Command logic all in one object, and because it can be used to prevent `Execute` calls happening within the `RelayCommand`. That's why I'm happy to try to fix `CanExecute` bugs in mvvmcross bindings as we find them.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to not use the built in functionality. Your approach with the booleans adds quite a lot of clutter to the code base.

Comment: Yes... but you're not the one who has to write all the bindings for MonoDroid and MonoTouch :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment :-)

Comment: Sorry - I should know better than making glib comments on StackOverflow. Basically, the MvvmCross framework includes binding libraries for iOS and Droid - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/vnext/Cirrious. These cover a lot (properties, commands, nesting, converters, etc) but they do have some gaps (incomplete impls of CommandParameters, Behaviors, etc). While those gaps exist, either someone (generally me) has to write the code to plug them or the users have to do their own workarounds - and htis may cause a little extra ViewModel clutter. Sorry again for the glib comment :)

Comment: The important point is that users get to share their ViewModels across WP7, Win8, iOS and Droid. mvvmcross quirks may add a little clutter, but it's better than writing the code separately for each platform :)

Comment: I've also amended my answer - I agree 100% that doing it using `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` is the better approach - but the workaround is still there if the user doesn't want to fix the bugs or wait for me to fix them. Thanks and sorry again :)

Comment: I will use the workaround, I am not sure I feel competent enough to work on the source code

Comment: @Stuart: I'm wondering whether you'd still (as in Dec 2014) would recommend to use separate IsEnabled boolean properties vs. CanExecute()?

Comment: [MvvmCross Documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding) >However, in MvvmCross, this auto-enable/disable binding isn’t currently widely supported - with support instead being given to secondary binding properties - e.g. to pairs of bindings...

Answer (score 5):

To follow up on Stuart's answer, it's easy to support both `ICommand.CanExecute` along with exposing properties to support Android and iOS Mvx bindings.

To do this, convert your typical `CanExecute(`) methods to properties, then add handlers to `CanExecuteChanged` that calls `RaisePropertyChanged` on the associated property.  Then use `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` as normal and the `PropertyChanged` event gets fired as well.

```
    ...

    // constructor
    public SomeClass()
    {

        DoSomethingCommand = new MvxCommand(OnDoSomething, () => CanDoSomething);
        DoSomethingCommand .CanExecuteChanged += (sender, args) => RaisePropertyChanged(() => CanDoSomething);
    }

    public bool CanDoSomething
    {
        get { ... }
    }

    ...
```