# Binding a Button to a ViewModel Command when the button is in a Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using the Navigation Drawer that's baked into the latest Android.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/Home_HomeView_DrawerLayout" >
<!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Home_HomeView_ContentFrame" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <!-- ... -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In my `HomeView`, I set the `Home_HomeView_ContentFrame` fragment based on the Selected Item

```
private void SelectItem(int position)
{
    var fragment = new HomeFragment(ViewModel);
    var arguments = new Bundle();
    fragment.Arguments = arguments;
    _actionBarTitle = ((HomeViewModel)ViewModel).NavigationItems[position].Text;

    SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                          .Replace(Resource.Id.Home_HomeView_ContentFrame, fragment)
                          .Commit();

    _topDrawerList.SetItemChecked(position, true);
    ActionBar.Title = _actionBarTitle;


    _navigationDrawer.CloseDrawer(_drawerInnerLayout);
}
```

The `HomeFragment` is to setup the BindingContext for MvvmCross

```
public sealed class HomeFragment : MvxFragment
{

    public HomeFragment(IMvxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle)
    {
        // A breakpoint below shows that the ViewModel does in fact contain the IPlayCommand as expected.
        BindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(Activity, new MvxSimpleLayoutInflater(layoutInflater), ViewModel);
        var rootView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Home_HomeFragment, viewGroup, false);

        Activity.Title = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.ApplicationName);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And inside the `Home_HomeFragment` layout, I have a button that is bound to an IMvxCommand. Note, this button is based on [@Stuart's example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20378672/124069)

```
    <FutureState.AudioBook.Droid.Ui.Controls.FsmButton
        android:id="@+id/Home_HomeFragment_PlayPauseIcon"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        local:MvxBind="Command PlayCommand; CommandParameter ." />
```

The ViewModel that it's binding to is currently quite simple.

```
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public IList<NavigationItem> NavigationItems;

    public HomeViewModel(IPlayCommand playCommand)
    {
        // playCommand is being resolved by the IoC
        _playCommand = playCommand;
    }

    private IPlayCommand _playCommand;
    public IPlayCommand PlayCommand
    {
        get { return _playCommand; }
        set
        {
            _playCommand = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => PlayCommand);
        }
    }
}
```

And when I put a BreakPoint on the `BindingContext` line of the `HomeFragment`, I can definitely see the ViewModel populated with the PlayCommand.

The problem I'm having is that the act of touching the button doesn't fire the `PlayCommand`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android inflate doesn't know about mvvmcross binding.

To use XML based binding, you must use `BindingInflate` - see the samples in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com with code in https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross - including fragments in n=26 - https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-26-Fraggle/Rock.Droid/Views/SubFrag.cs

There's also a nav drawer sample in http://motzcod.es/post/60427389481/effective-navigation-in-xamarin-android-part-1

Comment: Ah, that was it. I had to add Sub ViewModels and awkward bindings to make it work... but I see what's going on now. Thanks!