# MvxCommand CanExecute not working on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, mvvmcross

In my viewModel I have a Command property which is as follow

```
  public MvxCommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (loginCommand ==null)
            {
                return loginCommand=new MvxCommand(DoLogin,CanLogin);

            }

            return loginCommand;
        }
    }
```

This code works fine with WindowsPhone and the button is not enabled till all required validations are met. I am not able to achieve the same on Droid and Touch. Is there some special syntax for binding the command which also has CanExecute function. In none of N+1 examples I have found the utilization of CanExecute function in any of the command properties in the ViewModels. I  was expecting that similar behaviour to Windows Phone the button remains in the disable state till all validations pass successfully and then only it gets enabled. This behaviour is not working for Droid and Touch platforms.

In one of the [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951733/how-to-use-canexecute-with-mvvmcross) it was mentioned by Stuart Lodge that this behaviour still needs to be implemented on all platforms. But that was year back. I hope there would be some solution to it by now.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: For Android, a full button example is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370559/binding-views-to-icommand-canexecute

Answer (score 0):

add system.windows found in 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Windows.dll