# How to change image for imageView and disable ImgView click event

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the following code which will show the normal image for the imageView:

```
<ImageView        
    android:id="@+id/ImgNews"        
    android:layout_width="70dp"        
    android:layout_height="70dp"        
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"        
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"        
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"        
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"        
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"        
    android:src="@drawable/IconNews" />
```

Code behind:

```
imgNews.Click += (s, e) => {   
    var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(NewsDetailActivity));
    intent.PutExtra("newsId", _newsId);    
    StartActivity(intent);
};
```

How to do the following or implement it in MvvmCross, when there is no service available for this ImageView:

1) Change the Grey-out image for the ImageView (use `IconNews_Grey`)
2) Disable the click event

Comment: What do you mean with "no service available"? No internet? Your API is down? No cellphone service? Some other logic defines whether there is something to be done with your ImageView or not?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have many imageView act as button for user to click to navigate to other pages or Views. When user login to my app, I can detect his privilege-level, if his privilege is low, he can not access other ImageView required higher privilege, hence no service available.

Comment: MonoDroid is new to me. I need as much help as I can find. Appreciate anyone can help out.

Comment: The N + 1 Days of MVVM Cross is a tutorial made by the very creator of the library. You'll of course have to learn mvvm (you're using a MVVM library after all) and refactor a little, but the benefits of using it will be visible. What other problems do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MVVMCross you should be using the MVVM pattern. It means using a ViewModel and binding your values instead of setting the click handler on code behind.

The solution to your problem is fairly simple once you use these concepts. You must convert your click function into a `IMvxCommand`, create a property that controls whether or not you have a "service" and then use it to control the `CanExecute` of your command (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12951949/3465182))

The same can be done for your Image. Your property must return the drawable that needs to be shown: The regular one if you have a "Service" and the grey one otherwise.

You can find out more about how DataBinding and ViewModels work [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding) or by watching [N+1 Days of MVVM Cross](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DHDMNB_IeY)